# ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance, even when it is approved

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, erc20

Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance

Code:

```
ERC20Tokens[tokenTicker].token.approve(ERC20Tokens[tokenTicker].tokenHolder, 10);
    
emit tokenOwnerBalance(ERC20Tokens[tokenTicker].token.balanceOf(ERC20Tokens[tokenTicker].tokenHolder));
    
ERC20Tokens[tokenTicker].token.transferFrom(ERC20Tokens[tokenTicker].tokenHolder, address(this), 1);
```

Logs:

```
[
   {
      "from":"0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48",
      "topic":"0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925",
      "event":"Approval",
      "args":{
         "0":"0x7A2946b37399fa3F1C9EF81c7Bcf94AE1099D18F",
         "1":"0x95Ba4cF87D6723ad9C0Db21737D862bE80e93911",
         "2":"10",
         "owner":"0x7A2946b37399fa3F1C9EF81c7Bcf94AE1099D18F",
         "spender":"0x95Ba4cF87D6723ad9C0Db21737D862bE80e93911",
         "value":"10"
      }
   },
   {
      "from":"0x7A2946b37399fa3F1C9EF81c7Bcf94AE1099D18F",
      "topic":"0xcff530ae4ada35c1dd7ac314ef643b9eb7ae40665958ad5899e2fbc18865444a",
      "event":"tokenOwnerBalance",
      "args":{
         "0":"31000000"
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
ERC20Tokens[tokenTicker].token.approve(ERC20Tokens[tokenTicker].tokenHolder, 10);
```

This line approves the `tokenHolder` to spend **your contract's** tokens. Not the other way around.

So the `transferFrom()` fails because your contract is trying to spend the `tokenHolder`'s tokens.

---

If you want your contract to be able to spend `tokenHolder`'s tokens, the `tokenHolder` needs to execute the `approve()` function on the `token` from their address directly. Not through a contract in between.

Comment: This is a fork of the main Ethereum network and I am trying to send some USDC coins to my account. I found out that the owner of the tokens has some of them, so I use his address. Is there any other way to get multiple USDC coins in this smart contract?

Comment: @taranchik Unless you know the private key to the `tokenHolder` address (that you could use to execute the `transfer()` method directly from their address), they need to `approve()` the tokens first from their address directly. There's currently no other known way to spend tokens belonging to an other address without their key/approval.

Comment: Passing into the ERC20 openzeppelin constructor token address, would it be possible to get some of these tokens somehow?

Comment: @taranchik Only tokens of the contract that you're instantiating (with the constructor). But since the USDC contract is already instantiated, you can't execute its constructor for the second time.

Comment: So in other words is the approve function called in the browser via e.g MetaMask, or can it still be called in the contract if the user is invoking that function (is `msg.sender`)?

Comment: @Dominic Only directly (e.g. using MetaMask or web3js)... If it were invoked through another contract (_mediator_), the `msg.sender` in the target would hold the value of the _mediator_ address - not the user.

Comment: @PetrHejda thanks I thought so but had a param mixed up, got it working now 

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was a mistake of using `transferFrom` instead of `transfer` when transferring tokens from the contract.